# How many different ways can a string of $25$ magnetic beads be folded?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, physics, biology

I am using this model to estimate the number of different ways a protein containing $25$ amino acids can fold.

Each bead is unique but can magnetically attach to any other. They are arranged on the string in a unique order, but for simplicity assume that the string can stretch as much as needed.

I figured out that, just considering one bead attaching to every other bead (i.e. just 1 "fold" of the protein), over each bead in the string, there are overall $300$ unique ways the string can fold $(24+23+22+21+...+0)$.

Obviously the problem gets much more complex when multiple folds are considered.

An estimate, even just to an order of magnitude, is welcome, given sound mathematical reasoning.

How can a reasonable estimate (or even exact figure) be reached?

Comment: It is not clear to me how the beads can attach. Do I understand correctly that there are $25$ beads attached to eachother in a line, and then any bead can connect to any number of other beads? Even all beads connecting to all beads?

Comment: Also your example isn't clear to me. What does "one bead attaching to every other bead over each bead in the string" mean? Can you elaborate on how the count $24+23+\cdots+0$ comes about?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. The 25 beads are attached by a string that runs through them, but they are also magnetic and so the chain of beads can fold over and magnetically attach to itself. Assume each bead can magnetically connect to any other number of beads anywhere else on the chain.

Comment: As for my example of "one bead attaching to every other", I start by considering the first bead on the string: for just 1 fold, it can attach to any of the 24 other beads. Considering the second bead, it can also attach to any of the 24 other beads, but we already attached beads 1 and 2 when considering the first bead, so this configuration isn't unique, so just 23 unique configurations can be achieved with 1 fold via the second bead. Moving along the chain and considering each bead, the total number of unique configurations achievable via 1 fold comes to 24+23+22+21+...+0=300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there are $25$ beads in total, and hence $\tbinom{25}{2}=\tfrac{25\times24}{2}=300$ connections that can be made in total. The beads are attached in a string in a unique order, so these are $24$  connections that are fixed. This leaves $276$ available connections between beads. Each connection is either made or not made, yielding a whopping total of 
$$2^{276}\approx1.1214168\times10^{83},$$
configurations.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!